# WPF "e.Handled =true" equivalent in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

in WPF I used to using `e.Handled() = true` but in .NET MAUI I cant find the equivalent.

This is a piece of code where I wanted to use this

```
    private void _DoubleTapRecognizer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        **e.Handled() = true;** //error
        label1.Text = "You clicked twice!";
        
    }
    private void _SingleTapRecognizer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "You clicked once!";
    }
```

Basically, clicking once on a button should trigger one method, while clicking twice the other.
In wpf I would have used e.Handled to avoid trigging both events.

Can someone help me understand  why?
Thanks.

**EDIT**
This is the XAML code

```
<Button x:Name="doubleTapBtn" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="200" Text="Double tap me!">
        <Button.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="_DoubleTapRecognizer" NumberOfTapsRequired="2" />
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="_SingleTapRecognizer" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
        </Button.GestureRecognizers>
    </Button>
```

But I also tried this

```
        <Button x:Name="doubleTapBtn" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="200" Text="Double tap me!" Clicked="_SingleTapRecognizer">
        <Button.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="_DoubleTapRecognizer" NumberOfTapsRequired="2" />
        </Button.GestureRecognizers>
```

Comment: What precise events are you subscribing to? Chances are there's a more specific EventArgs type you could use...

Comment: It looks like that's a `EventHandler<TappedEventArgs>`, but `TappedEventArgs` doesn't have a `Handled` property. It might be worth filing a feature request.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think I will do it. Thank you!

Comment: There is no a such api in the maui can meet you requirement now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an build in option in MAUI, but if these two methods are your only requirement adding a bool to handle the double tab yourself might be an option.

```
private bool isDoubleTapHandled = false;

private void _DoubleTapRecognizer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isDoubleTapHandled)
    {
        isDoubleTapHandled = true;
        label1.Text = "You clicked twice!";
    }
}

private void _SingleTapRecognizer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isDoubleTapHandled)
    {
        label1.Text = "You clicked once!";
    }
    else
    {
        isDoubleTapHandled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi jeb, i'm interested to know if there is a "quick" solution like in WPF. 
Anyway thank you!
Even using your code both events are triggered.